# How to send error message from Django DeleteView?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Let's say there are two models `Parent` and `Child`. `Parent` to `child` is one to many relationship.

I am creating DeleteView for Parent model. Before deleting I need to check whether `Parent` has `Children`. If there are no `Children` then `Parent` model is deleted as usual. But if there are `Children` then I need to send error message to DeleteView confirmation page.

How can I achieve this using DeleteView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DeleteView inherites the [DeletionMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeletionMixin). What you can do is add `on_delete=PROTECTED` in your child model and override the delete method in your view to catch a `ProtectedError` exception. For the error message, see Django's [message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/).

models.py:

```
class Child():
    #...
    myParent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=PROTECTED)
```

views.py:

```
from django.db.models import ProtectedError

#...

class ParentDelete(DeleteView):
    #...
    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Call the delete() method on the fetched object and then redirect to the
        success URL. If the object is protected, send an error message.
        """
        self.object = self.get_object()
        success_url = self.get_success_url()

        try:
            self.object.delete()
        except ProtectedError:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Can not delete: this parent has a child!')
            return # The url of the delete view (or whatever you want)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override `delete` method and set a message using [Django's message framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/)

```
from django.contrib import messages

class DeletePArent(DeleteView):

   # ...

   def delete(self, request, *args, **args):
       object = self.get_object()
       if object.chidlren.count() > 0:
           messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Can't be deleted, has childern")
           return redirect('url-of-your-choice')
       return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```