# Django Add messages.error message to FormView

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I need to show an error message after form submission to the user. The condition is set inside the `form_valid` function of `FormView` but it is not form specific and I do not want to change the existing form logic. This is what I have tried -

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    if condition:
        messages.error(self.request, 'Please ...')
    return super(...)
```

Also tried this -

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    if condition:
        self.message = 'Please ...'
    return super(...)

def get_success_url(self):
    if self.message:
        messages.add_message(self.request, messages.ERROR, self.message)
    return self.success_url
```

Both of them don't work. In `DeleteView` this can be done by overriding `delete` function, how to do it for `FormView`?

Answer (score 1):

your first way is right but you need to also add to this in your html template so in views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
def form_valid(self, form):
    ...
    if condition:
        messages.error(self.request, 'Please ...')
    return super(...)
```

in HTML Template add this

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="alert alert-danger" style="list-style: none;">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}" {% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I've already added that. The issue is that the `request` variable being rendered is different. As I mentioned in the question for `DeleteView` you can [override it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54467081/how-to-send-error-message-from-django-deleteview). But how to do it for `FormView` is the problem

Comment: Yes my 2nd try is based on that answer. The HTML is also there. I will have to go with form validation for now